# Change default value of Select & search prompt Cognos 11.6

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I am trying to configure the Search And Select Prompt in Cognos Analytics 11 to change the default option from Starts with any of these keywords to Contains any of these keywords.

I found on internet some answers but they are not working with newer version of Cognos 11.6.

Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: You might want to list the actual version of the software you are using.  Cognos 11.6, if it ever is a real thing, wouldn't be released until probably around 2032.